# Failed Function For Ajax call jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this ajax call to my server side is there a failed function to determine of the ajax call has failed??? i think my code only shows the success function is there some sort of code?i just need to find out if my ajax call has failed. i'm using the new syntax for ajax call i think so. any help would be much appreciated thank you.

```
 $.post('authorSearch',
 {FirstName:$('#FirstName').val(),limit:row},
 function (data, status, obj) {
 alert('Success');
 });
```

i tried to do this but its not working

```
   $.post('authorSearch',
     {FirstName:$('#FirstName').val(),limit:row},
     function (data, status, obj) {
     alert('Success');
     },
function(data,status,obj){
alert('failed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .done .fail .always,

```
$.post({
  url: "url",
  data: data,
}).done(function() { alert("success"); })
  .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
  .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Everything is written in jquery documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/